# $injector:modulerr Module Error in angularjs 1

Tags: angularjs

Adding an ngMaterial to a module results in an error. I can not see what's wrong.

** success **

```
var routerObj = angular.module('note', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
```

** error([link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=socialnote&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngMaterial%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.0%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253DngAria%2526p1%253DError%25253A%252520%25255B%252524injector%25253Anomod%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.5.0%25252F%252524injector%25252Fnomod%25253Fp0%25253DngAria%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A6%25253A416%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A25%25253A136%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520b%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A24%25253A188)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A24%25253A431%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A287%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520n%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A355)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520g%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A135)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A304%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520n%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A355)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520g%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.0%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A135)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A40%253A60%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A135)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A304%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A135)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A304%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.0%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:40:60%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:304%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:43:164)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:20:449)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Ac%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js:21:259)) **

```
var routerObj = angular.module('note', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ngMaterial']);
```

Why does the difference in the above code cause an error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="note" ng-controller="homeCtrl" ng-class="animation">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">    
        <base href="/">
        <title></title>



        <!-- Angularjs -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AngularRoute -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AngularAnimation -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Angular Material Library -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- font awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/design/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- layout -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/design/layout.css">

        <!-- route animation -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/design/route-animation.css">
        <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">



            <script>
            (function(){

                //module init
                var routerObj = angular.module('note', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ngMaterial']);

                //route
                routerObj.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                        .when('/home', {templateUrl: '/template/home.html', animation: 'fade-in'})
                        .when('/popular', {templateUrl: '/template/list-popular.html', animation: 'slide-left'})
                        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home', animation: 'fade-in'});

                    //url hash code eliminate
                    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                });

              //controll layout(GNB Ctrl, Animation Ctrl)
                routerObj.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location){
                    // route animation
                  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, currRoute, prevRoute){
                    $rootScope.animation = currRoute.animation;
                  });
                    // current url(GNB show/hide controll)
                    switch($location.path()){
                        case "/home":
                            $rootScope.basicLayout = true;
                        break;
                        default:
                            $rootScope.basicLayout = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }); //end homeCtrl

            }());    
            </script>
      </head>
      <body>

        <p>ngRoute, ngMaterial</p>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular material have some dependencies

Try to add :

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>`

and :

`var routerObj = angular.module('note', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ngMaterial', 'ngAria']);`

Comment: The problem is resolved. Thank you for your advice. :D

Answer (score 0):

`ngMaterial` module is failing to load. Check that it is properly installed and configured. Check for errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Include the necessary scripts angular-aria.min & angular-messages.min and it should be in the below order.

```
<!-- Angularjs -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AngularRoute -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AngularAnimation -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Message module has been added. Thank you for your reply.